# Need help writing query requiring table joining

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Is anybody able to help me construct a query based on the schema in the attached image? I have been at this all morning but am hopeless with joins and cannot get it to work.

What I would like to be able to do is to select all rows from table 1 where table 4 ID referenced in table 1 is NOT available to the table 5 ID referenced in table 1.

Please let me know if that doesn't make sense, any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Database schema diagram]

Comment: what have you written so far

Comment: Nothing that achieves what I want! I have tried all sorts of join configurations without success. I really can't get my head around joins. I would post some examples of what I have tried but I deleted them as they didn't work.

Comment: Share sample data and what the result set would be. Your problem statement is confusing `select all rows from table 1 where table 4 ID referenced in table 1 is NOT available to the table 5 ID referenced in table 1.` I don't know what **NOT available to table 5** means. Use sqlfiddle.com to share sample data. Also, while JOIN's will probably be most efficient, this solution could probably be accomplished with `IN` or `EXISTS` functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured this out. The query I needed was:

```
SELECT Table1.Table1_ID
    FROM Table1
    INNER JOIN Table5
        ON Table1.Table5_ID = Table5.Table5_ID
    INNER JOIN Table2
        ON Table5.Table2_ID = Table2.Table2_ID
    INNER JOIN Table3
        ON Table2.Table2_ID = Table3.Table2_ID
    INNER JOIN Table4
        ON Table3.Table3_ID = Table4.Table3_ID
    WHERE Table4.Table4_ID <> Table1.Table4_ID
    AND Table1.Table5_ID = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure that I ahve understood the question, but does this query fits your needs?

```
 SELECT *
   FROM Table1
  WHERE Table1.Table4_ID NOT IN ( SELECT t1.Table5_ID
                                    FROM Table1 as t1
                                )
```